# Time Capsule and Thomson modem/router

Tags: network, wifi, airport, time-capsule

Just got a new airport time capsule (2013 model). The time capsule is put in bridge mode and the modem/router from my ISP (thomson 585 v8) is doing the router stuff (dhcp, nat). Time capsule is connected to modem/router via ethernet cable (100mbit is the interface of the router).

The question is: if I put the modem/router to bridge mode (my isp's configuration gives the option to bridge the modem) and turn the routing stuff to time capsule will my network become faster? Does the 100mbit conncetion between tc and modem slow down things in the local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect to the TC (via whatever speed you can get with wireless, or gigabit cable) then your communication to it and any other device on teh same LAN that is also connected to the local LAN is unaffected, it is only when you wish to send traffic over the 100mbit modem connection that you will be limited to it's speed, so basically your internet will be limited to 100mbit, and so long as that is faster than your ADSL/Cable connection anyway, then you will never notice it.

Comment: If the modem acts as router too, doesn't all the traffic get through the 100mbit connection for the routing? Even if I am transferring files from one wireless device to another (both connected to wirelessly to the time capsule).

Comment: If you have bridges the Modem, then it it essentially never seen, and only used when traffic routes outside of your LAN.  Your TC will handle all routing, and ona  flat local LAN traffic will only ever need to hit the TC to then be routed back out of the TC on whatever connection.

Comment: will bridged modem make the network faster than now? Now the tc is bridged and the modem is the lan router.

Comment: For wired connections, almost certainly, for Wireless, even with a faster max throughput on the TC, it really depends on too many local considerations to say yes with any accuracy, but you would expect so.

Comment: Plus other advantages are that your TC has a much nicer management interface than any normal router I have ever used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that even wireless to wireless file transfers would pass through the 100mbit connection because all traffic should go through the router in a lan.